# Finding downtimed checks

Tags: nagios

I need to find out all the checks which are in downtime state at present.

I suspect there are some checks which have been downtimed for months and we need to find out all of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JSON Query Generator:

```
http://mynagiosserver/nagios/cgi-bin/statusjson.cgi?query=downtimelist
```

That will give you a list of everything currently in downtime state.